# Importing csv data into OpenTSDB

Tags: opentsdb

I have successfully installed OpenTSDB ontop of a Cloudera Hadoop/HBase cluster.

My question is, I have reams of historical 1 minute stock data that looks like this:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume" 
12/30/2002,0930,24.53,24.65,24.53,24.65,762200
12/30/2002,0931,24.65,24.68,24.52,24.6,90400
```

.....

From the documentation in the QS Guide, it says in the Batch imports section:

./tsdb import your-file

When I try this on my data it throws an unhelpful exception.

Any hints on how to import this into OpenTSDB? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a script to transform your CSV in something that is in the OpenTSDB format.  The general format for OpenTSDB is `metric timestamp value tags`

For instance your sample could be written as follows:

```
stock.open 1041269400 24.53 symbol=XXX
stock.high 1041269400 24.65 symbol=XXX
stock.low 1041269400 24.53 symbol=XXX
stock.close 1041269400 24.65 symbol=XXX
stock.volume 1041269400 762200 symbol=XXX
stock.open 1041269460 24.65 symbol=XXX
stock.high 1041269460 24.68 symbol=XXX
stock.low 1041269460 24.52 symbol=XXX
stock.close 1041269460 24.6 symbol=XXX
stock.volume 1041269460 90400 symbol=XXX
```

Although since it appears that you're working with 1-minute periods, the open/close is redundant, so maybe this would be more appropriate:

```
stock.quote.1m 1041269340 24.53 symbol=XXX
stock.quote.1m 1041269400 24.65 symbol=XXX
stock.quote.1m 1041269460 24.6 symbol=XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small csv importer for opentsdb.

https://github.com/soeren-lubitz/csv-to-opentsdb

It works for CSV-Files in form of

```
Timestamp,Foo,Bar
1483342774,42.1,23.2
```

Hope this helps. Feedback would be appreciated.